# android thermal printer hex to barcode

Tags: java, android

We recently got a ms-100B(msp-100) thermal printer, everything prints fine except for the barcodeA and barcodeB, in the example they have the following hex:

```
43 4F 44 45 31 32 38 CC F5 C2 EB 0A 1D 6B 49 0A 7B 42 4E 6F 2E 7B 43 0C 22 38 0A
```

Which prints a 128code barcode.

```
13 51 00 18 15 02 FE A3 F8 82 3A 08 BA D2 E8 BA 02 E8 BA 1A E8 82 FA 08 FE AB F8 00 48 00 A3 21 28 5C 56 D8 0A DC D0 CD F5 60 B3 D9 38 00 E4 80 FE A6 A0 82 28 F0 BA 67 F0 BA 17 80 BA 9C F8 82 16 40 FE FF A8 00 0A
```

Which prints a QRcode.

The API has a method to get a string as hex but it's not working.

This is how they print in the demo application:

```
                        String tempStr = "2A 31 30 30 2A 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 0A";
                                                    m_BluetoothManager.PrintbarcodeA(tempStr);
```

and:

```
String tempStr = "13 51 00 18 15 02 FE A3 F8 82 3A 08 BA D2 E8 BA 02 E8 BA 1A E8 82 FA 08 FE AB F8 00 48 00 A3 21 28 5C 56 D8 0A DC D0 CD F5 60 B3 D9 38 00 E4 80 FE A6 A0 82 28 F0 BA 67 F0 BA 17 80 BA 9C F8 82 16 40 FE FF A8 00 0A";
                        m_BluetoothManager.PrintbarcodeB(tempStr);
```

However I'm unable to find a way to print custom barcode/QRcodes, how to obtain the hex?

Here is the [API document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVWWawJUlffX1VqUmJ6MjZIQ2c&authuser=0)

Here is the [User Manual](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVWWawJUlffX1VqUmJ6MjZIQ2c&authuser=0)

Here is the [API they provide](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVWWawJUlffX1VqUmJ6MjZIQ2c&authuser=0)

As you can see the API Document isn't really something useful.
Regards